# How to migrate tfs users and and the level of access

Tags: tfs, upgrade

I have already TFS and I want to upgrade to TFS 2017. Installed SQL SP 1 and TFS 2017. get backup from previous TFS configuration.and restore in new TFS.

But all user workgroup is blong to previous TFS. how can I fix all users automatically?

Comment: Lacking detail; are they in different domains?

Comment: @AndyNeillans not in domain.its workgroup

Comment: Ok; so I assume there are local accounts on the TFS 'server' that were used to commit code? Any reason why you can not just name the new 'server' the same as the old, which will mirror the naming convention that will be used?

Answer (score 1):

If you are moving your Team Foundation Server from one workgroup to another, you must re-create service accounts and user accounts in the new Team Foundation Server environment. Additionally, you must re-create any local accounts from the old Team Foundation Server on the new Team Foundation Server.

> The account names created on the new Team Foundation Server deployment
>   must match the names of the accounts from the original Team Foundation
>   Server deployment. This includes both user and service accounts. These
>   account names are used to identify and update the Team Foundation
>   Server database records as part of the move process.

Please see [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-clone-hardware#restore-the-tfs-databases) for more information.

Comment: thanks.but workgroup of old and new user is Different and not working.how to change workgroup of all old user to new workgroup?!

Comment: @user2254798 Please try the [TFSConfig Identities](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#identities) commands to change the workgroup.